# sqlite3 isn't getting installed

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, sqlite

Using Docker I face an issue. sqlite3 isn't getting installed. It's included in package.json, I tried to uninstall and reinstall but it doesn't work. Same issue when I clone the project and run `npm i`, but installing it again using `npm i -S sqlite3` works in Windows, but doesn't in the Docker container.

Docker-compose :

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    container_name: vacation_backend
    build: "./backend"
    image: backend:backend
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    network_mode: "bridge"
    env_file: "backend/.env"
```

Docker file :

```
FROM node:10-stretch

# COPY fix-proxy-apt /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99fixbadproxy
RUN apt update && apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm
RUN npm i -g npm forever

WORKDIR /app/backend
COPY ./ /app/backend

RUN npm install 
RUN npm uninstall --save sqlite3 
RUN npm install --save sqlite3
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR /app/backend
COPY backend.sh /backend.sh
RUN chmod +x /backend.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/backend.sh"]
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=\"development\" nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js",
    "build": "babel src --out-dir dist",
    "serve": "forever dist/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "@koa/cors": "^2.2.3",
    "@types/sequelize": "^4.28.1",
    "cron": "^1.7.1",
    "googleapis": "^40.0.0",
    "graphql": "^14.3.1",
    "graphql-relay": "^0.6.0",
    "graphql-sequelize": "^9.3.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "koa": "^2.7.0",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.2.1",
    "koa-graphql": "^0.8.0",
    "koa-router": "^7.4.0",
    "ldapjs": "^1.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.2.1",
    "sequelize": "^5.8.6",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "forever": "^1.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.0"
  }
}
```

Docker-compose build :

```
Step 9/15 : RUN npm install --save sqlite3
 ---> Running in a72a4cbda37c

> sqlite3@4.0.9 install /app/backend/node_modules/sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
[sqlite3] Success: "/app/backend/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v64-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node" is installed via remote
npm WARN project@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN project@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"}) 

+ sqlite3@4.0.9
added 70 packages from 65 contributors, updated 1 package and audited 7673 packages in 8.868s
found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Removing intermediate container a72a4cbda37c
```

Docker logs hash :

```
Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually
    at ConnectionManager._loadDialectModule (/app/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:81:15)
    at new ConnectionManager (/app/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/connection-manager.js:22:21)
    at new SqliteDialect (/app/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/index.js:14:30)
    at new Sequelize (/app/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:320:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/backend/dist/models/db.js:15:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/backend/dist/models/user.js:8:34)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/backend/dist/models/index.js:25:36)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #X
```

Comment: Can you add your `package.json`?

Comment: I've added it to the post

Comment: Can you try running `npm install --save sequelize` after your `npm install --save sqlite3` line in your Dockerfile?

Comment: I tried, same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Your `volumes:` declaration hides everything in the `/app` directory in your container, including the `/app/node_modules` directory.  I'd recommend deleting this block so you can run the application code that's actually built into your image (and doing live development outside of Docker).

Comment: Yeah it looks like the issue comes from persmission not able to delete/add sqlite3.node. Thanks for you input.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue tonight. The problem might be that the Node image doesn't include SQLite.

To confirm, you can start your app with `docker-compose up -d` to start your container in detached mode,  use the `exec` command to open up Bash in your container to access the container's command lie, then run the `which sqlite3` command inside your container to confirm you do not have it installed.

```
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker-compose exec backend /bin/bash
$ which sqlite3
$ exit
```

If running `which sqlite3` returns no output, then you don't have SQLite installed in your container. It was working in Windows because it's installed on the Windows OS.

To fix this, you'll need to install SQLite in your Dockerfile on line 4.

Dockerfile line 4 current:

```
RUN apt update && apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates
```

Dockerfile line 4 updated:

```
RUN apt update && apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates sqlite3
```

I'm still trying to figure out if there's a better way to work with SQLite inside a Node container, but I hope this helps!